# Login stays stuck in Usercontroller

Tags: php, authentication

I am programming a login system. When i click on submit, it stays in the `userController` and doesn't echo anything. i'm fairly new when it comes to programming so can anyone help me with this issue?

This is what it looks line in the template:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="top">
        <h1 id="title" class="hidden"><span id="logo"> <img src="assets/img/logo.jpg" alt="Commercium logo"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="login-box animated fadeInUp">
        <div class="box-header">
            <h2>Log In</h2>
        </div>
        <form method="post" action="../controller/userController.php">
            <input name="action" type="hidden" value="loginUser" required/>
        <label for="email">E-mail adres</label>
        <br/>
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="enter email">
        <br/>
        <label for="wachtworrd">Wachtwoord</label>
        <br/>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
        <br/>
        <button type="submit" value="Login" name="login">Sign In</button>
        <br/>
        <a href="index.php"><p class="small">
        </p></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is what it looks like in the controller

```
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $login = $user->loginUser($_POST['email'], $_POST['password']);
}
```

and this is the class

```
public function loginUser($email, $password)
{
    $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email= ? AND password= ? ");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $email, $password);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $row = $result->num_rows;

    if ($num_rows == 1) {
        echo 'U bent ingelogd!';
    }
    if ($num_rows == 0)
    {
        echo "geen gegevens";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$num_rows` is not defined in the `loginUser()` function. It should be

```
if ($row == 1) {
    echo 'U bent ingelogd!';
}
if ($row == 0){    
    echo "geen gegevens";   
}
```

Also you shouldn't be storing passwords in plain-text. Use php's `password_hash()` to hash the password and `password_verify()` to verify that the password from the html form matches the stored hash

Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279321/how-to-use-password-hash) regarding `password_hash()`

Also checkout the manual for [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

and

for [password_verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)